# SPFX Field Customizer: how to get full path of document in document library?

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I am creating a Field Customizer to display a hyperlink in a column in a document library view following this tutorial:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer

I need the absolute path of the document to create the result link.
I tried several things with `event.listItem.getValueByName()` but I only get values of the columns already in the view. How do I read all columns of the list item?

Comment: can you check with `event.listItem.getValueByName("FileRef")`  ?

Comment: Thank you that works! Its the relative URL, but I can use that. Weird enough FileRef is not in the event.listItem.fields array.

Comment: Cheers, happy to help. Have posted that as answer :) , you can accept it by ticking the checkmark besides the answer , like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `event.listItem.getValueByName("FileRef")` to get the path of the document in library. This will give you a server relative URL of the file in the document library.

If you want to have an anonymous link, then you can use `event.listItem.getValueByName('.spItemUrl')`. This will work for anonymous users.