# SPFX Field Customizer: how to get Id of item in list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, fieldcustomizers

My question relates to [SPFX Field Customizer: how to get full path of document in document library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245646/spfx-field-customizer-how-to-get-full-path-of-document-in-document-library).

How to I get the Id of the item on which the Field Customizer applies?

I have tried:

```
event.listItem.getValueByName("Id")
event.listItem.getValueByName("ID")
event.listItem.getValueByName(".Id")
event.listItem.getValueByName(".ID")
```

When Inspect the object I do not see the ID in the array:

[image]

I can however see the Id here:

[image]

Worst case, I suppose, is to get value from event.listItem["_values"] like this but it is really dirty

```
// This doesnt' work
let listItemId = event.listItem["_values"].find(item => item.key === "ID");  
// This works  
event.listItem["_values"].forEach((value: string, key: string) => {
console.log(key, value);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying `event.listItem.getValueByName('ID');` in `onRenderCell` method or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I am calling it in onRenderCell

Answer (score 0):

From the screentshot, the `event.listItem["_values"]` is a `Map` object, so you could get the ID like this:

```
let itemId=event.listItem["_values"].get("ID")
```