# When I display a list form, I want to get the list view ID and item ID

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, list-view, modern-experience, list-form

When I display a list form (modern UI), I want to get the list view ID and item ID and register them in the database.

What method can I use to achieve this?

Please share advise here.

Comment: Where and how are you displaying a list form?

Comment: The list form that appears when an item in the list view is clicked.
This is the default list form that appears on the right side of the screen.

Comment: From list view page, you can get view ID using: `_spPageContextInfo.viewId`

Comment: I was able to get a view ID using the method you taught me.
Thank you!!!!!
How can I get the item ID of the item being displayed?

Comment: Are you using SPFx application customizer on list view page or any other customization way? I will check for ways to get item ID accordingly.

Comment: I use Field Customizer.I really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Try this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298583/spfx-field-customizer-how-to-get-id-of-item-in-list. let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get list view ID**:

From list view page, you can get view ID using: `_spPageContextInfo.viewId`

**To get list item ID**:

Try below to get list item ID from SPFx Field Customizer:

```
const id = event.listItem.getValueByName('ID');
```

**Source**: [SentimentAnalyticsFieldCustomizer](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/676dcc2b7098af9387e6f9f13a9704c8dd014094/samples/react-field-text-analytics-api/src/extensions/sentimentAnalytics/SentimentAnalyticsFieldCustomizer.ts)

OR

```
let itemId=event.listItem["_values"].get("ID")
```

**Source**: [SPFX Field Customizer: how to get Id of item in list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298583/spfx-field-customizer-how-to-get-id-of-item-in-list)

Comment: I apologize, I did not make myself clear.I want to get ID of the item being displayed in the form list.
Perhaps if I can get the ID of the currently selected item in the list view, I can achieve my goal.

Comment: You can get the currently selected item ID on list form using power apps to customize the list form.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Resolved.